# Processing large text files in R (Speed up a loop for separating sentences)

Tags: r, performance, nlp, text-mining

I have large text documents (150K lines per document; 160 documents). Then I read them in as a large VCorpus and convert them to a dataframe it runs quite quickly. Now, I want to separate each sentence in rows and remove those that do not contain a certain keyword. Then I run the code R crashes. If I try it with one document the code runs for approximately 10 minutes.

The data (text) looks like this (just with much more text):

| Company1   | Company1 hat engaged in child safety in South Africa. The Community rewards this with great recognition. Charity  is a big part of the companies culture.

| Company2  | Company2 opened up several factories in the that do not pay the minimum wage. Affordable  Housing is not one of thair priorities.

There is also a small example structure below.

```
library(readr)
library(qdap)
library(tm)

corp <- VCorpus(DirSource("test"))

text <- as.data.frame(corp)
names(text)[1] <- 'doc_id'
names(text)[2] <- 'text'

text <- dput(text)

text <-  structure(list(doc_id = c("Company1.txt", "Company2.txt", "Company3.txt"
), text = c("Acucap's market cap on listing in 2002 was a meagre R372m, which would make it one of the smallest stocks in the real estate sector in today's terms. This may be a reflection of how the real estate sector of the JSE has evolved over the past 10 years. But, it is also amazing that Acucap - at a current market cap of more than R7bn - has managed to retain much of the same level of entrepreneurial spirit as at the time of its listing. Still at the helm is sector veteran Paul Theodosiou. The team has grown since listing. The core operational supporting team is Jonathan Rens, Gavin Jones and Craig Kotze, and the finance team is led by founding chief financial officer Baden Marlow. Acucap's physical portfolio is concentrated in retail, which comprises 74%, offices make up 24% and industrial takes the remaining 2%. Some of the larger retail properties include Festival Mall (the largest single asset in the portfolio) in Kempton Park, Bayside Mall in Tableview and Keywest shopping centre in Krugersdorp. The office portfolio includes assets like Mowbray Golf Park in Pinelands in the Cape, the Microsoft offices in Bryanston and 82 Grayston Drive in the Sandton CBD. Though small in Acucap's portfolio, the industrial portfolio is of a high quality and offers good scope for growth as expansion continues at the N1 Business Park in Midrand and the Montague Business Park in Cape Town. Acucap's other investments include a 17,2% shareholding in Sycom Property Fund (a fellow listed real estate property company) as well as a 100% shareholding in Sycom's management company. Sycom's other significant shareholder is Hyprop Investments. The latter's 33,9% stake in Sycom has been the subject of much speculation over the past few years as the ownership structure has created somewhat of an impasse. Acucap has, however, stated its strategic intent to retain Sycom as a separate fund. Company1 hat engaged in child safety in South Africa. The Community rewards this with great recognition. Charity is a big part of the companies culture.", 
"Australian copper producer Aditya Birla Minerals Ltd. said June 16 that there is a risk that the overall reserves at its Nifty copper mine in Western Australia may be adversely affected due to the effects of an earlier ground collapse at the mine. The company also said it will be unable to provide its annual reserve update until all investigative activities are finalized. Aditya Birla is expecting site costs for the June quarter to be in the range of A$17 million to A$19 million, higher than the earlier estimate of A$12 million to A$15 million due to higher-than-expected mine activity, unplanned maintenance on critical infrastructure and additional employee costs. The company was forced to halt operations at the Nifty mine in March following suspected underground subsidence, which led to the standing down of 350 mine employees until at least July 15. Phase two of probe drilling, which is being undertaken as part of efforts to assess mine safety, is progressing ahead of schedule and is now expected to be completed by the end of June instead of mid-July. Aditya Birla said preliminary observations from this second phase are similar to those from phase one drilling, in that there is less water being intersected between levels 16 and 20 than previously expected. Areas with potential to self-propagate into new sinkholes are being reviewed and, as Aditya Birla expected, the rock mass strength has deteriorated on top of mined-out areas. Management has begun an initial review of the results to identify new gaps and/or the need for additional confirmatory drilling. The first phase of the seismic system installation has been commissioned and is fully functional, albeit limited in coverage to upper parts of the mine. The pit has been dewatered with residual mud left at the pit sump. Aditya Birla added that while surface cracking has continued to develop in the area affected by the sinkhole, this was expected and does not present a hazard. However, washouts will occur after heavy rainfall, leading to widening and deepening of the cracks.", 
"In preparation for the potential completion of the merger with AGL Resources Inc., the board of directors of Nicor Inc. announced a special pro rata dividend. The dividend is contingent upon the merger being completed prior to Nicor's next scheduled dividend record date, Dec. 31, to ensure that \"shareholders continue to receive a dividend at the current rate until the closing of the merger,\" the company said. In a Nov. 1 news release, Nicor said its board of directors declared a pro rata dividend of 0.5 cent per share per day from Oct. 1 until and including the day before the merger effective date. The dividend is the daily equivalent of the current quarterly dividend rate of 46.5 cents per share. It will be paid to Nicor shareholders of record at the close of business on the day immediately before the effective merger date, which is expected in the fourth quarter. \"The dividend will be paid as soon as practical following the completion of the merger,\" Nicor said. \"This pro rata dividend is in addition to the previously announced Nov. 1 dividend that was paid to shareholders of record Sept. 30. Following the merger closing, AGL Resources is expected to pay a dividend at the rate of $0.004945055 per share, per day for the remainder of the current quarterly dividend period. These dividend payment scenarios, together with a similar plan announced today by AGL Resources, will synchronize the companies' dividends as of the merger effective date in accordance with the merger agreement.\" If the merger is not completed by Dec. 31, Nicor shareholders of record Dec. 31 will receive the regular quarterly dividend of 46.5 cents per share, payable Feb. 1, 2012, and a new pro rata dividend will be announced to ensure that shareholders receive a dividend at the current rate until the merger is completed. Company2 opened up several factories in the that do not pay the minimum wage. Affordable Housing is not one of thair priorities."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L))

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sckeywords <- c("Affordable Housing", "Benefit The Masses",
                "Charitability", "Charitable", "Charitably", " Charities ", " Charity ")
pat <- paste0(sckeywords, collapse = '|')

text2 <- (text) %>%
  separate_rows(text, sep = '\\.\\s*') %>%
  slice({
    tmp <- grep(pat, text, ignore.case = TRUE)
    sort(unique(c(tmp-1, tmp, tmp + 1)))
  })
```

Can I make it run faster somehow without needing more hardware capacity?
I have 16 GB of RAM and a 4 core CPU (i5-10210U).

Comment: Can you add a small example of `corp` with `dput`? Then it's easier to help you, thanks! And which hardware (cores/RAM) do you have available?

Comment: Thank you @starja for the response. I added that information. However, I used a small subset. The column "text" regularly consists of about 2 million characters per observation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to increase the speed:

1. I would use `data.table` instead of `dplyr` for this amount of data

```
text <-  structure(list(doc_id = c("Company1.txt", "Company2.txt", "Company3.txt"
), text = c("Acucap's market cap on listing in 2002 was a meagre R372m, which would make it one of the smallest stocks in the real estate sector in today's terms. This may be a reflection of how the real estate sector of the JSE has evolved over the past 10 years. But, it is also amazing that Acucap - at a current market cap of more than R7bn - has managed to retain much of the same level of entrepreneurial spirit as at the time of its listing. Still at the helm is sector veteran Paul Theodosiou. The team has grown since listing. The core operational supporting team is Jonathan Rens, Gavin Jones and Craig Kotze, and the finance team is led by founding chief financial officer Baden Marlow. Acucap's physical portfolio is concentrated in retail, which comprises 74%, offices make up 24% and industrial takes the remaining 2%. Some of the larger retail properties include Festival Mall (the largest single asset in the portfolio) in Kempton Park, Bayside Mall in Tableview and Keywest shopping centre in Krugersdorp. The office portfolio includes assets like Mowbray Golf Park in Pinelands in the Cape, the Microsoft offices in Bryanston and 82 Grayston Drive in the Sandton CBD. Though small in Acucap's portfolio, the industrial portfolio is of a high quality and offers good scope for growth as expansion continues at the N1 Business Park in Midrand and the Montague Business Park in Cape Town. Acucap's other investments include a 17,2% shareholding in Sycom Property Fund (a fellow listed real estate property company) as well as a 100% shareholding in Sycom's management company. Sycom's other significant shareholder is Hyprop Investments. The latter's 33,9% stake in Sycom has been the subject of much speculation over the past few years as the ownership structure has created somewhat of an impasse. Acucap has, however, stated its strategic intent to retain Sycom as a separate fund. Company1 hat engaged in child safety in South Africa. The Community rewards this with great recognition. Charity is a big part of the companies culture.", 
            "Australian copper producer Aditya Birla Minerals Ltd. said June 16 that there is a risk that the overall reserves at its Nifty copper mine in Western Australia may be adversely affected due to the effects of an earlier ground collapse at the mine. The company also said it will be unable to provide its annual reserve update until all investigative activities are finalized. Aditya Birla is expecting site costs for the June quarter to be in the range of A$17 million to A$19 million, higher than the earlier estimate of A$12 million to A$15 million due to higher-than-expected mine activity, unplanned maintenance on critical infrastructure and additional employee costs. The company was forced to halt operations at the Nifty mine in March following suspected underground subsidence, which led to the standing down of 350 mine employees until at least July 15. Phase two of probe drilling, which is being undertaken as part of efforts to assess mine safety, is progressing ahead of schedule and is now expected to be completed by the end of June instead of mid-July. Aditya Birla said preliminary observations from this second phase are similar to those from phase one drilling, in that there is less water being intersected between levels 16 and 20 than previously expected. Areas with potential to self-propagate into new sinkholes are being reviewed and, as Aditya Birla expected, the rock mass strength has deteriorated on top of mined-out areas. Management has begun an initial review of the results to identify new gaps and/or the need for additional confirmatory drilling. The first phase of the seismic system installation has been commissioned and is fully functional, albeit limited in coverage to upper parts of the mine. The pit has been dewatered with residual mud left at the pit sump. Aditya Birla added that while surface cracking has continued to develop in the area affected by the sinkhole, this was expected and does not present a hazard. However, washouts will occur after heavy rainfall, leading to widening and deepening of the cracks.", 
            "In preparation for the potential completion of the merger with AGL Resources Inc., the board of directors of Nicor Inc. announced a special pro rata dividend. The dividend is contingent upon the merger being completed prior to Nicor's next scheduled dividend record date, Dec. 31, to ensure that \"shareholders continue to receive a dividend at the current rate until the closing of the merger,\" the company said. In a Nov. 1 news release, Nicor said its board of directors declared a pro rata dividend of 0.5 cent per share per day from Oct. 1 until and including the day before the merger effective date. The dividend is the daily equivalent of the current quarterly dividend rate of 46.5 cents per share. It will be paid to Nicor shareholders of record at the close of business on the day immediately before the effective merger date, which is expected in the fourth quarter. \"The dividend will be paid as soon as practical following the completion of the merger,\" Nicor said. \"This pro rata dividend is in addition to the previously announced Nov. 1 dividend that was paid to shareholders of record Sept. 30. Following the merger closing, AGL Resources is expected to pay a dividend at the rate of $0.004945055 per share, per day for the remainder of the current quarterly dividend period. These dividend payment scenarios, together with a similar plan announced today by AGL Resources, will synchronize the companies' dividends as of the merger effective date in accordance with the merger agreement.\" If the merger is not completed by Dec. 31, Nicor shareholders of record Dec. 31 will receive the regular quarterly dividend of 46.5 cents per share, payable Feb. 1, 2012, and a new pro rata dividend will be announced to ensure that shareholders receive a dividend at the current rate until the merger is completed. Company2 opened up several factories in the that do not pay the minimum wage. Affordable Housing is not one of thair priorities."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L))

library(data.table)

sckeywords <- c("Affordable Housing", "Benefit The Masses",
                "Charitability", "Charitable", "Charitably", " Charities ", " Charity ")
pat <- paste0(sckeywords, collapse = '|')

setDT(text)

text <- text[, .(text = unlist(tstrsplit(text, "\\.\\s*", type.convert = TRUE))),
             by = "doc_id"]
text <- text[grepl(pat, text)]
```

2. You can try to speed up the regex. One possibility is to create a trie, e.g. with [trieregex](https://github.com/ermanh/trieregex). In your case, it would be:

```
trie_1 <- "(?:Charitab(?:ility|l[ey])|\\ Charit(?:ies\\ |y\\ )|Benefit\\ The\\ Masses|Affordable\\ Housing)"
text <- text[grepl(trie_1, text)]
# or without the white space around the last two words
trie_2 <- "(?:Charit(?:ab(?:ility|l[ey])|ies|y)|Benefit\\ The\\ Masses|Affordable\\ Housing)"
text <- text[grepl(trie_2, text)]
```

However, in the short example, using fixed patterns was actually the fastest (checked with `microbenchmark`), so you could try this:

```
text <- text[grepl(sckeywords[1], text, fixed = TRUE) | grepl(sckeywords[2], text, fixed = TRUE) |
             grepl(sckeywords[3], text, fixed = TRUE) | grepl(sckeywords[4], text, fixed = TRUE) |
             grepl(sckeywords[5], text, fixed = TRUE) | grepl(sckeywords[6], text, fixed = TRUE) |
             grepl(sckeywords[7], text, fixed = TRUE)]
```

If this is still too slow, try to use other tools like `awk` or `sed`.

3. Use parallel processing. You could try to parallelise everything:

- make a list of the files to read in and send parts of this file list to the different cores/workers. They then read in the files so that you don't need to send big files to different cores (you can also first try to skip this and start with your original code if the file is not too big)
- make a clean data.table and filter it
- return the data and join everything

When you run into memory issues, you could also try to save the cleaned data.tables separately in the workers instead of returning them.

For a parallel framework, I'd recommend [`foreach`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=foreach) or the [`futureverse`](https://www.futureverse.org/)

### Edit

Here is a regex that ignores the case of the first character. However, I'm not an expert on regexes, so maybe there are better ways to optimise the regex!

```
trie_2 <- "(?:[Cc]harit(?:ab(?:ility|l[ey])|ies|y)|[Bb]enefit\\ [Tt]he\\ [Mm]asses|[Aa]ffordable\\ [Hh]ousing)"
```

Comment: Thanks @sarja,  that already helps a lot. However, I get much different results if I run it for one document (dplyr: 1600 obs.; data.table: 600 obs.). I believe this is due to the missing ignore.case = TRUE argument of the grepl function. Then I try to apply it I get the unused argument (ignore.case = TRUE) error. Is this caused by the data.table formating?

Comment: Ah, no the regexes in the answer are case sensitive so far. I've added a regex that is case insensitive (it's faster than using your naive regex approach with `ignore.case = TRUE`). However, I'm not an expert on regex and maybe there are better ways to improve it. You could ask the regex question separately. I also haven't tried how fast the combinations of `grepl` with  `fixed = TRUE` is for the different upper/lower case combinations.

Comment: Also, in your code, do you try to capture the rows above and below the regex match with `tmp - 1`/`tmp + 1`? This is not implemented in my answer.